# mobile detection in webpage Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token || in console

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I have a script to detect if user is using mobile:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ 
var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
if (mobile) ||  (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.site.com/mobile/';
}
//]]>
</script>
```

However I get this, what is it wrong with ||?

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ||
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the expressions need to be wrapped in parenthesis.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ 
var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
if ((mobile) ||  (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.site.com/mobile/';
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: You always have to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The boolean expression you are testing must be wrapped in parens.

```
if ((mobile) ||  (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)))
```